# Cheap device that have HDMI in and can run root-accessible Linux that can access this video data

Tags: linux, video, hdmi, video-capture

Is there a device (laptop, TV, single-board computer, smartphone) that has HDMI port that can consume video (1080p @ 30 fps) and give it to Linux running on it (that can save it to file or encode it with FFmpeg or whatever)?

HDCP is optional. Usable hardware video encoder is nice.

Comment: Do you mean an HDMI [capture device](http://www.amazon.com/Elgato-Capture-PlayStation-gameplay-1080p/dp/B00840353W/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1449627492&sr=1-1&keywords=hdmi+capture)? Or like a whole device (e.g. laptop) which can display input video from HDMI?